# How can I extract the value of key-value pairs in a comma-separated format?

Tags: powershell

I downloaded a txt file containing data in the following format:

> "data1":111,"data2":22,"data3":3,"data4":4444444, and so on.

I need to extract the data such that:

```
$data1 = 111
$data2 = 22   
$data3 = 3
...and so on.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the file is exactly as you described, the data you want to extract is comma separated.  You can retrieve the file content using the [Get-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) cmdlet.

```
Get-Content myFile.txt | Out-String
```

The command above pipes the output of Get-Content out to a single string. Otherwise, if the file had multiple lines then you could have retrieved a [collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx) of strings. A single string is preferable in this case, because you can `split` the string based on delimited values into a collection.  For example:

```
PS C:\> $string = '"data1":111,"data2":22,"data3":3,"data4":4444444'
PS C:\> $data = $string.split(",")
PS C:\> $data
"data1":111
"data2":22
"data3":3
"data4":4444444
```

From there, you can break the string down into numerical values by identifying what needs to be removed.  Looks like everything before and including the colon.  So we want to `-replace` these values, like so:

```
# Create an empty array to store the parsed data.
PS C:\> $parsedData = @()
# For each element in the $data array, replace content up to the first colon.
PS C:\> foreach($i in $data) { $parsedData += $i -replace ".*:", "" }
PS C:\> $parsedData
111
22
3
4444444
```

From there, it would be trivial to reassign these array elements to whatever variable name you'd like.  You may want to view [about_Comparison_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) or this blog on [string manipulation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx) for a more general introduction towards solving these sorts of problems.

---

Lastly, these sort of key-value pairs are great for the [Hash Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) data structure. Be sure to check it out when you're feeling more comfortable with powershell. It would ultimately offer a much cleaner way to handle your data than the solution you proposed... although a simple array may be fine too if the key is simply "dataX".

Answer (score 1):

using spilt,then using split for '"data2":22',then get substring.

```
#method 1
$rawTxt='"data1":111,"data2":22,"data3":3,"data4":4444444'
$rawTxt -split ',' | ForEach-Object {
   $temp= $_ -split ':'
   "{0}={1}" -f $temp[0].Substring(1,$temp[0].Length-2),$temp[1]
} | ConvertFrom-StringData



#method 2
$rawTxt = '"data1":111,"data2":22,"data3":3,"data4":4444444,"data5":589'
$regex = [regex] '"(?<name>\w*)":(?<value>\d*),?'
$match = $regex.Match($rawTxt)
while ($match.Success) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $match.Groups['name'].Value
        Value = $match.Groups['value'].Value
    }
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

Comment: A reference to your Chinese blog article, written just in time to answer this question? Why don't just answer it here in English? You can include a link to your blog in your profile if you want.

Comment: @Neolisk, sorry, I realized my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" -delimiter "," | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ":" -PropertyNames Part1, Part2
```